# how do i work the I2C peripheral on STM32L412

Tags: embedded, stm32, i2c

I'm trying to get a 4 channel DAC working through the I2C peripheral on an STM32L412, I've read through the reference manual but I'm a little confused and my I2C doesn't work. So far, it sends out the first address byte OK, it seems like there's an ACK bit, but then nothing - just a stop condition. I'm trying to output 8 bytes - four 12bit values split over two bytes each.

I've set it up using the STM32cube but I found I had write a few things manually afterward - below is the initialisation. I'm operating in fast mode, 400KHz - ive used 300nS as the rise / fall times and the peripheral is clocked at 16MHz

Can anyone help me? I don't know what im doing wrong

```
static void MX_I2C2_Init(void)
{
 hi2c2.Instance = I2C2;
 hi2c2.Init.Timing = 0x00610611;
 hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress1 = 192;
 hi2c2.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
 hi2c2.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
 hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
 hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
 hi2c2.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
 hi2c2.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
 if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2) != HAL_OK)
{
   Error_Handler();
 }
 /** Configure Analogue filter 
 */
 if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c2, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
 {
   Error_Handler();
 }
 /** Configure Digital filter 
*/
if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c2, 0) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}
}
```

i've included this in the main setup before the loop

```
 I2C2->TXDR = DACdata[0]; //pre-load output register
 I2C2 ->CR2 &= ~(1<<25); //AUTOLOAD = 0
 I2C2 ->CR2 |= 0b1100000<<1; //enter slave address
 I2C2 ->CR1 |= 1 << 6 | 1<<1; //enable finish interrupts
 I2C2 ->CR2 |= 0b1000 << 16; //bytes to send = 8
 I2C2 ->CR2 |= 1<<13; //start DAC
```

and this is my interrupt, but the program never gets here

```
void I2C2_EV_IRQHandler(void)
{
   if (I2C2->ISR & 1<<1)
  {
    i2ccounter++;
    I2C2->TXDR = DACdata[i2ccounter];
  }

 if (I2C2->ISR & 1<<6)
      {
        i2ccounter = 0;
        I2C2->TXDR = DACdata[0];
        I2C2 ->CR2 |= 1<<13; //start counter
      }
 HAL_I2C_EV_IRQHandler(&hi2c2);
}
```

and the main loop

```
int main(void)
{
 HAL_Init();

SystemClock_Config();

MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_I2C2_Init();
MX_ADC1_Init();
MX_TIM1_Init();
MX_TIM2_Init();

I2C2->TXDR = DACdata[0]; //pre-load output register
I2C2 ->CR2 &= ~(1<<25); //autoend off
I2C2 ->CR2 |= 0b1100000<<1; //enter slave address
I2C2 ->CR1 |= 1 << 6 | 1<<1; //enable finish interrupts
I2C2 ->CR2 |= 0b1000 << 16; //bytes to send = 8
I2C2 ->CR2 |= 1<<13; //start DAC

while (1)
{
}

}
```

Comment: using magic numbers is the best way of getting into the troubles.

Comment: i don't know what that means

Comment: 0b1000 << 16 etc etc

Comment: yeah i wasn't sure if this is legit, but it does what it's supposed to

Comment: use humar readable definitions from STM headers. Who will check what is at position 16 in the particular register. Avoid as a plaque

Comment: im not sure what you mean - i checked it in the simulator, the registers all update as expected

Comment: It's super hard to read, both for people who will need to maintain your code later and for people on StackOverflow. You are less likely to get an answer...

Comment: which header file do i find the names for the individual bits in the registers? Ill change them

Comment: I'm confused by the code you shared.  Are you intending to use the STM32 HAL or not?  Where is `MX_I2C2_Init()` called from?  Where is the I2C interrupt enabled?  Please download the [STM32CubeL4](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubel4.html) software package and review the I2C examples included within it.

Comment: I use cube to set up the HAL - configure the peripherals, but other than that I operate the registers directly, I find it less confusing and HAL is often very slow. The interrupts are enabled in the preamble by turning them on directly in the CR1 register. Thanks for the tip, i wasn't aware there was a STM32cubeL4 package

Comment: You either use the HAL or you write directly to the registers - I would not attempt to do both if I were you.

Comment: P__J__ is not saying your code doing the wrong thing (though the evidence is against you on that one), rather that it is bad practice to use literal rather then symbolic constants.  Not least because to understand your code, those of whom you are asking assistance will have to wade through the reference manual to even figure out what `I2C2 ->CR2 |= 1<<13` might do, and no one is going to work that hard for you.  STM32 I2C peripheral is horribly difficult to code, my first impression of your driver is that the is not nearly enough code.

Comment: What @P__J__ is talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: got it. i thought putting a code next to it would be sufficient. Why shouldn't I mix the HAL with writing to drivers? I usually generate HAL initialisation with cube then write to the drivers otherwise